# Найти повторяющиеся слова в тексте и посчитать количество повторений каждого из слов C#

Tags: c#, функции, поиск, текст

*Оффтоп: я новичок, пытаюсь постигать язык программирования, но мне как самоучке это не быстро идет.*
**Суть задачи:** есть текстовый файл (лог от программы, для примера взял его). В каждом предложении текста может быть ключевое слово, или даже несколько раз повторяться одно и тоже слово *(пример ключевых слов {"Info", "Trace", "Debug", "Warn"})*. Требуется посчитать сколько раз каждое ключевое слово фигурировало в тексте, а если в некоторых предложениях одно и тоже ключевое слово употреблялось более 1 раза, то посчитать за 1 повторение. Предложение имеет вид:{"instance":"2C768A564246", "code":"-1157555488", "product":"", "version":"52065", "component":"Server.Service", "severity":"Trace", "time":"2018-04-29T03:01:10.0609148+03:00", "message":"Vacuum таблицы: \"public\".\"passport\", время выполнения 00:00:00.7131481", "thread":"9", "activity":"", "transaction":"", "exception":""}

Я научился читать текст из файла, но пока не понял как сделать функцию поиска. Мой код для чтения текста из файла:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadFileAndCount
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"d:\Test.log";
            string line;

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                StreamReader file = null;
                try
                {
                    file = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8);
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (file != null)
                        file.Close();
                }

            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь с написанием функции поиска по ключевым словам и выводу количества повторений каждого ключевого слова.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните: вы будете хранить ключевые слова в коде программы, или же вы хотите просто посчитать, сколько раз встречается каждое слово в тексте?

Comment: Я надеялся хранить ключевые слова в коде. Думал над тем, чтобы попробовать сделать массив, создать функцию поиска и уже из нее обращаться к массиву за каждым ключевым словом. Но вероятно я не совсем правильно придумал решение. Поэтому и обратился за помощью.

Comment: а как же иначе эмпирически вывести эти ваши ключевые слова?) Так что в любом случае придётся создать массив. Если бы просто количество, сколько раз встречается каждое слово в тексте - можно было бы без этого) Так, и, как я понял, в рамках одного предложения (кстати, что у вас считается предложением?) ключевое слово считать только один раз, даже если его там много?)

Comment: Предложение имеет вид:{"instance":"2C768A564246", "code":"-1157555488", "product":"", "version":"52065", "component":"Server.Service", "severity":"Trace", "time":"2018-04-29T03:01:10.0609148+03:00", "message":"Vacuum таблицы: \"public\".\"passport\", время выполнения 00:00:00.7131481", "thread":"9", "activity":"", "transaction":"", "exception":""}
Однако, в редких случаях (если это лог ошибки) в одном таком предложении может употребляться пару раз слово, например: Trace

Comment: В идеале конечно хорошо, если бы ключевое слово считалось 1 раз на предложение, но мне для понимания хватит чтобы все ключевые слова посчитались, чтобы я понял принцип работы функции поиска :)

Comment: [Метод String.Contains (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Andrey добавьте ваш пример предложения в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попытаюсь расписать алгоритм:

1. Хорошо бы хранить искомые слова в словаре `Dictionary<string,int>`
   Где ключ-это слово, а значение- это кол-во встречаемости
2. Приступаете к чтению файла. С этим у вас проблем нету, как я вижу.
3. Теперь мы столкнулись с проблемой. А что мы считаем за предложение? Могут быть всякие цитаты и все такое и многие многие другие случае. Т.е нельзя считать однозначно за предложение `[!.?]`. Если у вас 1 предложение=1 строчки, то эта проблема отпадает.
4. Вызываем на предложении метод `Split()`(или `RegEx.Split()` так как `Split()` может захватить знаки препинания...) с делением по пробелу и получаем коллекцию слов
5. Проводим итерацию этих слов через наш словарь. Если значение есть в словаре, то делаем инкремент.

Вы привели такой пример в комментах:

> {"instance":"2C768A564246", "code":"-1157555488", "product":"",
>   "version":"52065", "component":"Server.Service", "severity":"Trace",
>   "time":"2018-04-29T03:01:10.0609148+03:00", "message":"Vacuum таблицы:
>   \"public\".\"passport\", время выполнения 00:00:00.7131481",
>   "thread":"9", "activity":"", "transaction":"", "exception":""}

Это похоже на JSON, что может облегчить вам задачу в разы.

Описываете класс, который соответствует этой структуре, далее используете библиотеку для десериализации из JSON, например [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) и парой строк кода заполняете класс данными.

Comment: 4. Вызываем на предложении метод Split() - в логах часто встречается конструкция [info], info-. Может искать через предложение.Contains()? И код легче будет, и не надо париться с количеством повторений внутри предложения.

Comment: @vusaldev, я бы рекомендовал бы второй вариант. Описать класс лога и десериализовать из JSON. Тогда вообще парсить ничего не потребуется.

Comment: Извините, коллеги, пришлось прерваться на командировку. Вернулся буду думать над вашими советами. Спасибо всем кто проявил участие! Вопрос пока не закрываю, т.к. я эту задачу еще не решил, может потребоваться еще раз ваша помощь :)